# Python plotting loop - where is my memory going?

Tags: python, memory, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have the following loop which plots a figure and then saves it onto disk, repeated iteratively 120 times. Python's RAM use initially is around 2.2GB (Data and SeaP arrays are 120x721x1440) so quite large to start. However RAM use increases on each loop iteration, so much so that by quarter of the way through (i = 30) RAM use is 7.9GB and rising. Is there a memory leak? Or a way I can prevent this increasing, I see no reason as to why it should be increasing - code is trivial. Code in the loop in question below.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import minimum_filter, maximum_filter


Lon = np.linspace(-180,180,1440)
Lat = np.linspace(-90,90,721)
Lon,Lat = np.meshgrid(Lon,Lat)


m = Basemap(projection='laea',width=10000000,height=6500000,resolution ='l',lat_ts=50,lat_0=55,lon_0=-25)
X, Y = m(Lon, Lat)

def Make_SLP(PRMSL,X,Y,Cont_Int,window=30):

    mn = minimum_filter(PRMSL, size=window, mode='wrap')
    mx = maximum_filter(PRMSL, size=window, mode='wrap')         
    local_min, local_max = np.nonzero(PRMSL == mn), np.nonzero(PRMSL == mx)
    clevs = np.arange(900,1100.,4.)

    csl = m.contour(X,Y,PRMSL,np.arange(950,1050,Cont_Int),colors='k',linewidths=0.3)
    xlows = X[local_min]; xhighs = X[local_max]
    ylows = Y[local_min]; yhighs = Y[local_max]
    lowvals = PRMSL[local_min]; highvals = PRMSL[local_max]

    xyplotted = []
# don't plot if there is already a L or H within dmin meters.
    yoffset = 0.022*(m.ymax-m.ymin)
    dmin = yoffset
    for x,y,p in zip(xlows, ylows, lowvals):
        if x < m.xmax and x > m.xmin and y < m.ymax and y > m.ymin:
            dist = [np.sqrt((x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2) for x0,y0 in xyplotted]
            if not dist or min(dist) > dmin:
                plt.text(x,y,'L',fontsize=16,fontweight='bold',
                         ha='center',va='center',color='b',clip_on=True)
                plt.text(x,y-yoffset,repr(int(p)),fontsize=9,
                         ha='center',va='top',color='b',
                         bbox = dict(boxstyle="square",ec='None',fc=(1,1,1,0.5)),clip_on=True)
                xyplotted.append((x,y))
    # plot highs as red H's, with max pressure value underneath.
    xyplotted = []
    for x,y,p in zip(xhighs, yhighs, highvals):
        if x < m.xmax and x > m.xmin and y < m.ymax and y > m.ymin:
            dist = [np.sqrt((x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2) for x0,y0 in xyplotted]
            if not dist or min(dist) > dmin:
                plt.text(x,y,'H',fontsize=16,fontweight='bold',
                         ha='center',va='center',color='r',clip_on=True)
                plt.text(x,y-yoffset,repr(int(p)),fontsize=9,
                         ha='center',va='top',color='r',
                         bbox = dict(boxstyle="square",ec='None',fc=(1,1,1,0.5)),clip_on=True)
                xyplotted.append((x,y))
    return plt


for i in range(0,100):

    plt = Make_SLP(np.random.rand(721,1440)*1000,X,Y,10,window=30)


    print i
```

Comment: Will need to show a complete example to reproduce. The error is likely not in the loop. Hint - memory created by objects outside the loop which are incremented or used inside the loop will cause memory usage to increase on every loop iteration.

Comment: It seems you're always using the same basemap, just with a different contourplot. Have you tried keeping the figure and the basemap alive and only remove and redraw the contour? If this is not an option, you might want to delete (`del`) the figure to see if this makes a difference. For further help here, you would indeed need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Could you run this only one iteration and compare the memory usage?

Comment: I would like to submit the whole code but it is a few thousand lines long! Is there a way to view how much memory each variable/object is using in python?

Comment: Here is a MCV now that I've edited the question; why does RAM use increase? Its something to do with plt.